# Style cannot be set after the stage is visible

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, stage, fxmlloader

This is the function. The error is in  stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED); which says style cannot be set after the stage is visible. Can you help me out here where i should declare this in the function and suggest some code editing needed if any.

```
@FXML
public void Showmain() {
    // Handle Button event.
    myButton3.setOnAction((e) -> {
        System.out.println("Project screen");




    //  FXMLLoader fxmlLoader1= new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Projectscreen.fxml"));
           try {

               Node node = (Node) e.getSource();               
                Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
             //   
                scene = stage.getScene();
                stage.setWidth(1280);
                stage.setHeight(968);
                stage.centerOnScreen();
                stage.setTitle("Welcome to Kdaf");
              //  stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED); 
                //stage.setResizable(false);
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Projectscreen.fxml"));
                Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                scene.setRoot(root);

           } catch (IOException exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }

           });







}
```

Comment: it's documented :-) Way out is to set the style before showing the stage

Comment: Then it shows null pointer exception.

Comment: Time for a SSCCE, as it sounds like something wrong with the code you are not showing ;-)